# How to read a big data (50G+) from memory rather than local disk in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, memory, load

I am debugging my deep learning model. Every time run the code, a .npy file (50G+) will be loaded as training data, and it takes 10+ mins. So, is there some methods to read data from memory directly. For example, create a process reading the .npy file. Every time training process starts, it can read memory from the reading process, and save a lot of time.

Comment: Can you use a smaller amount of data for debugging?

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I need to observe the training accuracy at first several epochs.  If it does not  satisfy me，I  will modify  the model, and restart the training.

Comment: If you need to test many different parameters and compare them, you should use something like [`scikit-learn`'s `GridSearch`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/grid_search.html). This way you only load the input data once and run the code many times, each time with a different parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Redis. It will work fast because Redis saves data in memory. You can load data to Redis and latter read it fast